# QTableView not updated on dataChanged

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I'm not able to update the layout of a QTableView when the Model data is changed.
I tried with dataChanged.emit(index,index), with layoutChanged.emit() and also, as a last resort, with reset(). None of it worked.
My code:

```
class SettingsDialog(QDialog, settings_design.Ui_settingsDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.weekdayTable = QTableView(self.weekdayPage)
        weekdayModel = self.loadMeetingData(self.meetingsData['weekdayList'])
      #weekdayModel.dataChanged.connect(self.updateTable)
        self.weekdayTable.setModel(weekdayModel)

    def updateTable(self):
        self.weekdayTable.repaint()

class MeetingsModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, columns):
        QStandardItemModel.__init__(self, data, columns)
        with open('meetings.config.json') as f:
            self.meetingsData = json.load(f)

    def setData(self, index, value, other):

        self.meetingsData['weekdayList'][int(index.row())][index.column()] = value
        with open('meetings.config.json', 'w+') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(self.meetingsData))

        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        # self.layoutChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am confused. is `weekdayModel` a `MeetingModel`? Also if you are emitting with `(index, index)` doesn't updateTable need to accept those parameters it being a Slot?

Comment: @busfault Yes, weekdayModel is a MeetingModel. I don't understand what you mean by "updateTable need to accept those parameters it being a Slot". Anyway, theoretically, dataChanged.emit should trigger a repaint(), . In this case updateTable() is not needed.

Comment: If you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can simply copy-past-execute I can help further. Now I can only give some general things to look for. 1) verify that `setData` is actually called. 2) verify that `dataChanged` is emitted by connecting it to a slot that prints a debug message. 3) In that slot check that the topLeft and bottomRight indexes are valid and if so, print their row and column values.

Comment: @sica07 What I mean is that a connected **Slot** (`updateTable`) must have the same signature as the **Signal** (`dataChanged`). I would highly recommend using decorators for this i.e. `@QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QModelIndex, QtCore.QModelIndex)`
before the `def updateTable(self, topLeft, bottomRight)` (note that I added the two parameters that the Signal sends to be received by the Slot)

Comment: @sica07 Where are you changing the Layout? also, how is `SettingsDialog` being instantiated?

Comment: @busfault The dataChanged is emitted and the updateTable is triggered. Also,  topLeft and bottomRight are vaild QModelIndex objects.

Comment: @bausfault: thank you for your help! I found a way to solve the problem (see answer below).

Comment: @titusjan Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem by taking other approach.

**Old approach** (the elegant one):

I extended the `QStandardModelItem`'s `setData` **method** with a function to save the modified data into a file.

**New approach:**

When the `dataChanged` **signal** is emitted by the `QStandarItemModel` the connected **slot** (`writeChangedData`) will write the changed data to the file. In other words, I moved the functionality from `setData` to the slot.

**The code:**

```
class SettingsDialog(QDialog, settings_design.Ui_settingsDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.weekdayTable = QTableView(self.weekdayPage)
        self.weekdayModel = self.loadMeetingData(self.meetingsData['weekdayList'])
        self.weekdayModel.dataChanged.connect(self.writeModifiedData)
        self.weekdayTable.setModel(self.weekdayModel)

    def writeModifiedData(self, topLeft, bottomRight):
        self.weekdayModel['weekdayList'][int(topLeft.row())][topLeft.column()] = value
        with open('meetings.config.json', 'w+') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(self.weekdayModel))
            f.close()
```